# Is it possible to reach hidden SMB/CIFS share from Android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, linux, windows, es-file-explorer, cifs

I am using `ES file explorer` to browse my Windows shares. Now I made some SMB/CIFS shares with Linux, and it is able to make "hidden" shares, like this:

```
[priv]
comment = Private
path = /media/VIDEO/prov
available = yes
valid users = dims device
read only = no
browseable = no
public = yes
writable = yes
```

I can use this share from Windows if explicitly enter it's name. But looks like `ES File explorer` can't remember the link if it is not browseable.

How to overcome?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a share directly in ES. From the **LAN** window, click **New**. In the **Server** text box, type the address and path of the share (e.g. `server/priv`), and fill in the rest of the form appropriately.

Comment: It does not work for me this way. If enter only server name or server IP, then it creates a server icon. But if I enter servername plus share name (like `server/priv`) it says "Server not found". For any share, both browseable or not.